# changing zend application but didn't work

Tags: zend-framework2, environment-variables

I have change the database name in zend application but it still using the old database name.I have tried to fetch env but its empty.I have changed the user name but it didn't effect anything.I have check the cache folder nothing in it.I have also set env var in vhost but still same issue.Is there any composer command so i can clear the cache or set env.

Comment: just remove all files in `data/cache` folder ;)